# Depth-First Search on graph

Tags: ocaml, depth-first-search

I've been doing a tutorial in OCaml. The tutorial taught me how to do a breadth-first search on a graph, which I can implement fine. However, I've been struggling with an algorithm for a depth-first search, which is one of those things where the tutorial goes, "We suggest you try this on a depth-first method, but we won't tell you how to do it."

I'm trying to implement it like so: `let rec dfs graph start end`. Which is to say, I've been trying to do it where I take in a list of edges (`graph`), a starting node (`start`), and an ending node (`end`).

I've created my graph using a list of edges...

```
let edges = [
  ("a", "b"); ("a", "c");
  ("a", "d"); ("b", "e");
  ("c", "f"); ("d", "e");
  ("e", "f"); ("e", "g")
];;
```

However, I'm totally lost about where to go from here.

Comment: The usual one-sentence summary is that depth-first search is the same as breadth-first search except that you replace the queue of unvisited nodes with a stack. You might try modifying your breadth-first search implementation in this way.

Comment: A function to list the successors of a node may make things easier for you.

Answer (score 4):

So, I did it but I find it strange that you represent a graph as a list if you have to search in it. A map would be much better. Anyway, here's how it's done :

```
let edges = [
  ("a", "b"); ("a", "c");
  ("a", "d"); ("b", "e");
  ("c", "f"); ("d", "e");
  ("e", "f"); ("e", "g")
];;

let successors n e = 
  List.map (fun (_, v) -> v) (List.filter (fun (u, _) -> n = u) e)

let dfs graph start f =
  let rec rdfs visited node =
    if not (List.mem node visited) then
      begin
        f node;
        let s = successors node graph in
        List.fold_left rdfs (node::visited) s
      end
    else visited
  in rdfs [] start

 let () = let _ = dfs edges "a" print_string in ()
```

First thing, define a `successors` functions which will give you every direct successor of a node (the `List.filter` part gets you the edges, the `List.map` part split the resulting edges in two parts and keep only the second one (the first one is naturally the node for which you are searching the successors).

The `dfs` function defines an internal function that do two things, checking if the node we are working on was already visited or not.

- If yes, nothing changes, we just return the same list of visited nodes (and maybe some other things depending on what you want to do with your search).
- If no, then
- We apply the function we gave to `dfs` to the current node,
- We add this node to the visited nodes,
- We take his successors,
- We apply the function to each one, (here, there's a small trick, since we have

  `List.fold_left : ('a -> 'b -> 'a) -> 'a -> 'b list -> 'a`

  and

  `rdfs : string list -> string -> string list`

  instead of writing

  `List.fold_left (fun visited node -> rdfs visited node) ...`

  we can write

  `List.fold_left rdfs ...`

  (something to do with this strange thing called Lambda Calculus and some rule called *eta conversion* which states that :

  `λ x · ux    η    u      (x ∉ fv(u))` (`fv(u)` being the free variables of u) :-p) (what it means is that in OCaml, if you write `fun x -> f x` you could have written `f` instead, it is strictly equivalent.)
- We return the visited nodes list in which all the visited nodes have been added

Hope I helped.

Comment: lambda calculus pros: ??, cons: readability..what are the pros?

Comment: The pros are that you have an unified language to talk about the theoretical foundations of your language. It's not that hard to read if you consider it as a logical language and it doesn't have the limitations of real programming languages

Comment: Stylistic suggestion, but `List.map (fun (_, v) -> v) (List.filter (fun (u, _) -> n = u) e)` => `List.( e |> filter (fun (u, _) -> n = u) |> map snd )`

Comment: @Chris I understand the stylistic suggestion but I'd rather having something that is easy to read when I answer questions on SO :-) In this case, I find `|> map snd` difficult to read, hence my choice